# Designing a fluent Javascript interface to abstract away the asynchronous nature of AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, fluent-interface

How would I design an API to hide the asynchronous nature of AJAX and HTTP requests, or basically delay it to provide a fluent interface. To show an example from Twitter's new [Anywhere](http://platform.twitter.com/js-api.html) API:

```
// get @ded's first 20 statuses, filter only the tweets that
// mention photography, and render each into an HTML element
T.User.find('ded').timeline().first(20).filter(filterer).each(function(status) {
    $('div#tweets').append('<p>' + status.text + '</p>');
});

function filterer(status) {
    return status.text.match(/photography/);
}
```

vs this (asynchronous nature of each call is clearly visible)

```
T.User.find('ded', function(user) {
    user.timeline(function(statuses) {
        statuses.first(20).filter(filterer).each(function(status) {
            $('div#tweets').append('<p>' + status.text + '</p>');
        });
    });
});

function filterer(status) {
    return status.text.match(/photography/);
}
```

It finds the user, gets their tweet timeline, filters only the first 20 tweets, applies a custom filter, and ultimately uses the callback function to process each tweet.

I am guessing that a well designed API like this should work like a query builder (think ORMs) where each function call builds the query (HTTP URL in this case), until it hits a looping function such as each/map/etc., the HTTP call is made and the passed in function becomes the callback.

An easy development route would be to make each AJAX call synchronous, but that's probably not the best solution. I am interested in figuring out a way to make it asynchronous, and still hide the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  What is a fluid interface and how is async not fluid?

Comment: @mike - with async requests, we specify a callback for each async request which breaks the fluidity/fluency of the chained method. compare the two examples above to see which one seems fluid/fluent.

Comment: Not that this question specifies jQuery, but [using deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) can abstract that sort of call quite well... There are other deferred implementations available too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Give a look to the following article published just a couple of days ago by Dustin Diaz, Twitter Engineer on @anywhere:

- [Asynchronous method queue chaining in JavaScript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/)

He talks about a really nice technique that allows you to implement a fluent interface on asynchronous methods, basically methods chained together independent of a callback, using a really simple Queue implementation.

Comment: Don't know how you found it, but this looks like exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: just awesome.. and great to see the Anywhere API was behind this article too, reading up on it now - thanks!

Comment: @Anurag: You're welcome, I hope you enjoyed the article. By the way, Dustin no longer works on Yahoo!, he is now working at Twitter on the @anywhere API :)...

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now dead

Answer (score 5):

I'm developing [FutureJS](http://github.com/coolaj86/futures) which was originally based on [Crockford's promises](http://github.com/coolaj86/futures/blob/master/crockford_promise.js) ([original slides](http://www.slideshare.net/douglascrockford/crockford-on-javascript-act-iii-function-the-ultimate)). The current goal is to be the Async Toolbox of JavaScript and eliminate chaining clutter.

### Futures.chainify(providers, consumers, context, params)

Asynchronous method queueing allows you to chain actions on data which may or may not be readily available.
This is how Twitter's @Anywhere api works.

You might want a model which remotely fetches data in this fashion:

```
Contacts.all(params).randomize().limit(10).display();
Contacts.one(id, params).display();
```

Which could be implemented like so:

```
var Contacts = Futures.chainify({
  // Providers must be promisables
  all: function(params) {
    var p = Futures.promise();
    $.ajaxSetup({ error: p.smash });
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/me/friends', params, p.fulfill);
    $.ajaxSetup({ error: undefined });
    return p.passable();
  },
  one: function(id, params) {
    var p = Futures.promise();
    $.ajaxSetup({ error: p.smash });
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + id, params, p.fulfill);
    $.ajaxSetup({ error: undefined });
    return p.passable();
  }
},{
  // Consumers will be called in synchronous order
  // with the `lastResult` of the previous provider or consumer.
  // They should return either lastResult or a promise
  randomize: function(data, params) {
    data.sort(function(){ return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); // Underscore.js
    return Futures.promise(data); // Promise rename to `immediate`
  },
  limit: function(data, n, params) {
    data = data.first(n);
    return Futures.promise(data);
  },
  display: function(data, params) {
    $('#friend-area').render(directive, data); // jQuery+PURE
    // always return the data, even if you don't modify it!
    // otherwise your results could be unexpected
    return data;
  }
});
```

Things to know:

- `providers` - promisables which return data
- `consumers` - functions which use and or change data

  - the first argument must be `data`
  - when returning a promisable the next method in the chain will not execute until the promise is fulfilled
  - when returning a "literal object" the next method in the chain will use that object
  - when returning `undefined` (or not returning anything) the next method in the chain will use the defined object
- `context` - `apply()`d to each provider and consumer, thus becoming the `this` object
- `params` - reserved for future use

Alternatively you could use synchronous callback chaining - what you may have seen elsewhere as chain().next() or then():

```
Futures.sequence(function(callback) {

    $.getJSON("http://example.com", {}, callback);

}).then(function(callback, result, i, arr) {

    var data = transform_result(result);
    $.getJSON("http://example.com", data, callback);

}).then(...)
```

I named it `sequence` rather than `chain` since _.js already has a method named `chain` and I'd like to use _.methodName for my library as well.

[Take a peek](http://coolaj86.github.com/futures/) and [let me know what you think](http://groups.google.com/group/futures-javascript).

FuturesJS will work alongside jQuery, Dojo, etc without issue. There are no dependencies. It will work with Node.js (and Rhino when using env.js).

=8^D

P.S. As to the ORM / MVC fix - you can check out [JavaScriptMVC](http://JavaScriptMVC.com) and [SproutCore](http://SproutCore.com). I'm also working on my own solution called TriforceJS, but I don't have anything ready for release yet.

P.P.S Example of `promisables`

```
var doStuff = function (httpResult) {
    // do stuff
  },
  doMoreStuff = function (httpResult) {
    // do more stuff
  };

function fetchRemoteData(params) {
  var promise = Futures.promise();
  $.getJSON("www.example.com", params, promise.fulfill, 'jsonp');
  return promise;
}

p = fetchRemoteData(params);
p.when(doStuff);
p.when(doMoreStuff);
```

Comment: Is a `promisable` basically like a proxy?

Comment: A promisable is an object with the methods `.when()`, `.fail()`, `.fulfill()`, `.smash()`.

It allows you to "return" data in an asynchronous fashion.

Example: See the P.P.S I added above.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX synchronous issue, I believe, has already been abstracted away by libraries such as jQuery (i.e. its [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which allows you to specify async or synch operation through the *async* property). The synchronous mode, if chosen, hides the asynchronous nature of the implementation.

jQuery is also an example of a fluent interface and chaining. There are other libraries that do the same.  Saves you reinventing the wheel - gets you rolling right away with what you are looking for.

If this works as an answer then you get some good automatic browser compatibility across these features. That stuff takes a long while to build out from scratch.

I see Twitter's new Anywhere API notes jQuery - maybe everything is already there if you do some digging.

Comment: I don't want the AJAX requests to be synchronous at all, but still have something like `Object.getDetails().doSomething().display()` where `getDetails()` is a asynchronous AJAX call. It can still be achieved with jQuery, but jQuery does not already have this built in. See the article in @CMS's answer for more information. XMLHttpRequest provides an option to make synchronous calls, and that doesn't hide the asynchronous nature, but totally eliminates it.