# Chaining asynchronous methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var res = myAjax.post();
```

myAjax is basically my own ajax wrapper (asynchroneous). I don't necessary need the chaining, but i'd like to be able to do the call like shown above. I'd like a callback to be handled by the object itself. I've read about asynchroneous method queues, but, honestly, couldn't fully understand it. I know i could use a synchroneous ajax call, but it should be possible to do it asynchroneously as well if i understand it correctly. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. You're describing a synchronous arrangement, but you say you want the call to be asynchronous. It can only be one or the other.

Comment: *"it should be possible to do it asynchroneously as well if i understand it correctly"* --> You don't.

Comment: JQuery does this so it should be possible. Please read this if you think it's impossible: http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/ The problem with this article is that i don't fully understand it...

Comment: @Marius: This article is about function chaining, not about value assignment.

Comment: Oh ... So they still run asynchroneously and return immediately?

Comment: Damn ... So that's what seemed wrong. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Marius: The *whole point* of asynchronicity is to return immediately instead of waiting until an operation is finished. ;-) So the value assignment has to happen when the statement is finished (e.g.: in the onSuccess event handler).

Comment: @Tomalak: i understand that perfectly. But i was fooled by my not so perfect English when i read that article into thinking that was actually possible ;] I guess i'll have to look for a way to write an ajax call with as little code as possible instead.

Comment: @Marius, give a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796375/designing-a-fluent-javascript-interface-to-abstract-away-the-asynchronous-nature), I understand what you are trying to do, implementing a fluent interface, to "hide" the asynchronous nature of Ajax requests...

Answer (score 0):

I've done a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P7eXF/) that might be something along the lines of what you mean...

In that demo, there are two types of objects: `MyAjax` which has the 'post' method as above, and a `MyRes` object with a `getData` method that will return `null` until the async call has successfully completed. After it has completed, it will return the data fetched from the ajax call.

In the demo, I have a function checking for the response every second, but the `post` method also handles a callback which allows you to be notified when the ajax call has completed successfully.

I don't know *why* you'd want to do it this way, but it is doable.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. There are probably a few ways of doing this, but i guess it's still not the same. To answer your question, i simply want to reduce the ammount of the code needed to write an ajax call - that's all. Lots of callbacks simply clutter the code so i thought i could clean it up a bit.