# how to avoid callback chains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I need a bunch of functions to be called in strict order. It's also very important that the next function waits until the previous one has finished.

Right now I'm using chained callbacks:

```
callMe1(function(){
    callMe2(function(){
        callMe3(function(){

            callMeFinal();

        });
    });
});
```

This works but seems to be a little ugly.

Any suggestions for a different approach?

Comment: I'd try to give you a good answer on how to rearrange your code to avoid these situations, but that very simple code sample doesn't really go into why those functions are currently chained like that...

Comment: A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796375/designing-a-fluent-javascript-interface-to-abstract-away-the-asynchronous-nature) that I asked last year

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you use jQuery, then you can use [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to chain the functions.

```
$(document)
  .queue(callMe1)
  .queue(callMe2);
```

where `callMeX` should be of form:

```
function callMeX(next) {
    // do stuff
    next();
}
```

Comment: Queues are awesome... One suggestion, instead of binding to `$(document)` bind to `$({})` -- that way the functions inside the queue can use `this` to reference that same shared object.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement a "stack" system:

```
var calls = [];

function executeNext(next) {
    if(calls.length == 0) return;
    var fnc = calls.pop();
    fnc();
    if(next) {
        executeNext(true);
    }
}

/*To call method chain synchronously*/
calls.push(callMe3);
calls.push(callMe2);
calls.push(callMe1);
executeNext(true);

/*To call method chain asynchronously*/
calls.push(callMe3);
calls.push(function(){
    callMe2();
    executeNext(false);
});
calls.push(function(){
    callMe1();
    executeNext(false);
});
```

Comment: guess this would be the best solution if there wasn't such a thing as jquery's queues, appriciate it

Comment: @Meister - in the call method chain asynchronously, , how to invoke the callbacks? since there's only push action

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would help you, but there is a great article on [using deferreds in jQuery 1.5](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/).  It might clean up your chain a bit...

Also, my answer on [Can somebody explain jQuery queue to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me/3314877#3314877) has some examples of using a queue for ensuring sequential calls.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass parameters to the functions, I do not believe you can at the time of this writing. However...

```
function callMe1(next) {
    console.log(this.x);
    console.log("arguments=");
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("/funct 1");
    this.x++;
    next();
}
function callMe2(next) {
    console.log(this.x);
    console.log("arguments=");
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("/funct 2");
    this.x++;
    next();
}
function callMe3(next) {
    console.log(this.x);
    console.log("arguments=");
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("/funct 3");
    this.x++;
    next();
}
var someObject = ({x:1});
$(someObject).queue(callMe1).queue(callMe2).queue(callMe3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your functions, arguments intact, with an anonymous function that plays along with `.queue` works too.

#### Passing Arguments in Jquery.Queue()

```
var logger = function(str, callback){
    console.log(str);
    //anything can go in here, but here's a timer to demonstrate async
    window.setTimeout(callback,1000)
}

$(document)
.queue(function(next){logger("Hi",next);})
.queue(function(next){logger("there,",next);})
.queue(function(next){logger("home",next);})
.queue(function(next){logger("planet!",next);});
```

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rS4y4/