# Empty curly braces inside jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the snippet, 
`$({}).queue(function(next){})`
 what does `$({})` represent? Why do people use this form?

I got the code from [this answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263068/empty-curly-braces-inside-jquery/29263255?noredirect=1#comment46728693_29263255).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Your [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263068/empty-curly-braces-inside-jquery/29263255?noredirect=1#comment46728693_29263255) that you're referring to the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230333/how-to-avoid-callback-chains/5230395#5230395) changes things **markedly**.

The code in that answer:

```
$(document)
  .queue(callMe1)
  .queue(callMe2);
```

...and then there's a comment suggesting using `{}` instead of `document`:

```
$({})
  .queue(callMe1)
  .queue(callMe2);
```

You would do that to set up a chain of calls, where subsequent calls in the chain don't occur until previous ones say they're done. What they do can be synchronous or asynchronous. It's kind of an early form of promises.

Let's take an example: Suppose I want to do three things, one after another, and each of those things might or might not do something asynchronous, like an animation. We could do this:

```
$({}).queue(theFirstThing)
     .queue(theSecondThing)
     .queue(theThirdThing);
```

...and later functions wouldn't get called until the earlier functions said they were done.

Example:

```js
$({}).queue(theFirstThing)
     .queue(theSecondThing)
     .queue(theThirdThing);

function theFirstThing(next) {
  // What I do is asynchronous: Fade out the a1 element,
  // then call the next function in the chain if any
  $("#a1").fadeOut("slow", next);
}
function theSecondThing(next) {
  // What I do is synchronous
  $("<p>Hi there</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  
  // Chain to next if any
  next();
}
function theThirdThing(next) {
  // What I do is asynchronous: Fade out the a2 element,
  // then call the next function in the chain if any
  $("#a2").fadeOut("slow", next);
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">a1</div>
<div id="a2">a2</div>
<div id="a3">a3</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Original Answer**:

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-object) tells us:

> **jQuery( object )**
>
> **object**
>   
>   Type: PlainObject
>   
>   A plain object to wrap in a jQuery object.

E.g., it wraps a jQuery instance around a plain object. We're used to jQuery instances being wrapped around one or more DOM elements, but they can be wrapped around other things as well.

Then they're doing [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback) on the resulting jQuery object:

> **.queue( [queueName ], callback )**
>
> **queueName**
>   
>   Type: String
>   
>   A string containing the name of the queue. Defaults to fx, the standard effects queue.
>
> **callback**
>   
>   Type: Function( Function next() )
>   
>   The new function to add to the queue, with a function to call that will dequeue the next item.

So that tells us what it's doing: Wrapping a jQuery object around a plain object, then calling `queue` to put something in the default animation queue for that jQuery object, even though there are no elements in it to animate.

> Why do people use this form?

I've never seen that used. I can't think of any reason to use it as shown in your question, it just ends up calling the function immediately, during the `queue` call, as we can see here:

```js
$({}).queue(function(next){
  snippet.log("Function called");
  next();
});
snippet.log("queue call complete");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: That surely is strange. Thank you T.J.!

Comment: yes T.J. I found it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230333/how-to-avoid-callback-chains/5230395#5230395

Comment: @JenniferMassey: `$(document).queue(...)` is **very different** from `$({}).queue(...)`, and multiple `.queue` calls change things from just a single one. I think that question and its answer explain why they're using this quite well.

Comment: @JenniferMassey: I've updated the answer to address the code in that other question and its answers.

Comment: T.J. thank you so much for all the efforts. I begin to see the sense, still a lot  to digest ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've used $({}) before when instantiating a variable that will later be replaced with a real JQuery object, so that in case of an unexpected result, the original value is still a valid JQuery object.  It may not really be necessary in that case.

Upon inspection, one major difference between $() and $({}) is the value of .length.  0 and 1, respectively.  Good question and conversation. +1

Comment: *"It may not really be necessary in that case."* It isn't, just use `$()`.

Answer (score -2):

Whenever no context is passed in to a jQuery object, the context is
set to 'document'. Since $() has no context, the context then
defaults to document. Same with doing $([]) ans $({}).

Comment: Thank you! Then why not simply $()?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gmq84a9k/ - if it would mean the same as "document" does, why doesn't this worK?

Comment: @Jenn It is too early to thank; **this answer is incorrect**.