# What's the best way to cycle through each data-XXX cell synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table with a column which has a data- attribute in each row, like `<td data-XXX="####">`, I want to find each cell (which can be done with

```
$table.find("[data-XXX]")
```

unless someone has a better way), take the value of the data-XXX attribute, pass it to an AJAX query, parse the JSON result, and place the results in the `<td>` with the associated data-XXX field. And maybe the toughest requirement of all… I'd like it all done synchronously, to minimize a lot of server requests all at once… so the next AJAX call isn't made until the previous table cell is filled.

So… my question is specifically - what's the best way to cycle through each data-XXX cell synchronously?

Comment: This title is absolutely useless....

Comment: Uh.. Put all the values in an Array, pass it to the server, then send back an Array of results to the client?

Comment: A much better way to do this would be to gather all the data you need and pass it to the server as a JSON blob in one single AJAX call.

Comment: @DanielBeck (btw, weird, I know two different Dan Becks)… the problem is the server calls take a while and it times out if I try to do them all at once… and speed for this specific field isn't too important, so I rewrote it so it can just do one at a time and fill in as the user is looking at other table data (which is more important to show right away anyway).

Comment: Based on the words in the description, the title of this question should be something like this: "How to cycle through N consecutive async ajax calls, not starting the next until the previous one finishes".

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963590/how-to-synch-javascript-callbacks/15964626#15964626) for a code sample of serializing asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you want the ajax calls done one after the other so the next one doesn't start until the previous one finished.  The ajax calls themselves will still be asynchronous (as they should).  You can do that like this:

```
function processData() {
    var items = $table.find("[data-XXX]");
    var cntr = 0;

    function next() {
        if (cntr < items.length) {
            var obj = items.eq(cntr);
            // do your ajax call with obj
            $.ajax(...).done(function(results) {
                // process results returned from ajax call
                // ...

                // now do the next iteration
                ++cntr;
                next();
            });
        }
    }
    // start first iteration
    next();
}
```

The basic idea is that you set up two state variables (your jQuery object that contains the list of objects to process and an index variable that keeps track of which one to process next).  Then, you create an inner function that you use for each iteration.  In the completion handler for the ajax call, you increment your counter and then start the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table.find("data=XXX").each(function(){
   var tdEle = this;
});
```

Also checkout dataset:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset

Comment: The key to this question is "so the next AJAX call isn't made until the previous table cell is filled."