# Success handling in custom javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

If I make an ajax call, I can add success handling.  I want to add similar logic to my custom functions.

I have 6-10 custom functions that MUST be run sequentially or independently.  They don't typically run independently so I have them daisy-chained now by calling the next function at the end of the previous but that is messy to read and does not allow for separate execution.

I would love to have something like this:

```
function runall(){
    runfirst().success(
        runsecond().success(
            runthird()
    ))
}
```

I have had other situations were I would like to add `.success()` handling to a custom function, but this situation made it more important.

If there is another way to force 6-10 functions to run synchronously, that could solve this problem, but I would also like to know how to add success handling to my custom functions.

#### I tried the following based on @lanzz's suggestion:

I added `.then()` to my function(s):

```
$bomImport.updateGridRow(rowId).then(function () {
        $bomImport.toggleSubGrid(rowId, false);
});


var $bomImport = {
  updateGridRow: function (rowId) {
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_rev"]').html($("#mxRevTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_itemno"]').html($("#itemNoTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_used"]').html($("#usedTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_partSource"]').html($("#partSourceTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_partClass"]').html($("#partClassTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_partType"]').html($("#partTypeTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_partno"]').html($("#mxPnTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_descript"]').html($("#descTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_qty"]').html($("#qtyTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_custPartNo"]').html($("#custPartNoTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_crev"]').html($("#custRevTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_u_of_m"]').html($("#uomTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_warehouse"]').html($("#warehouseTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_standardCost"]').html($("#stdCostTxt").val());
    $('#' + rowId + ' td[aria-describedby="bomImport_workCenter"]').html($("#wcTxt").val());
    var defferred = new $.Deferred();
    return defferred.promise();
}};
```

The code correctly goes to the end of updateGridRow, gives no errors, but never gets back to call the second function.

I also tried the following as was suggested @Anand:

```
workSheetSaveExit(rowId, isNew).save().updateRow().toggle();
function workSheetSaveExit(){
    this.queue = new Queue;
    var self = this;
    self.queue.flush(this);
}
workSheetSaveExit.prototype = {
  save: function () {
    this.queue.add(function (self) {
        $bomImport.workSheetSave(rowId, isNew);
    });
    return this;
  },
  updateRow: function () {
    this.queue.add(function (self) {
        $bomImport.updateGridRow(rowId);
    });
    return this;
  },
  toggle: function () {
    this.queue.add(function (self) {
        $bomImport.toggleSubGrid(rowId, false);
    });
    return this;
  }
};
```

Which didn't work.

**Final Solution**
For a great explanation of how to use deferred and make this work see here:
[Using Deferred in jQuery](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/)

Comment: You want to read about [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and/or [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: For some reason, those do not work.  I think the issue is my function is not a jquery function.  I call it like this:$bomImport.getWorksheet();  when I add .then, or .done, etc it does not have that method

Comment: jQuery functions are not magic. See example in answer below.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help so far.  I know it can work, I am probably missing something really simple.

Comment: Your `updateGridRow` function is not asynchronous and you do not need to defer its result. It makes no sense to handle synchronous code in the same manner as asynchronous. But still: when you use deferreds, at some point when your code has finished its work, you need to call `deferred.resolve()` in order to notify your listeners that you are ready, or `deferred.reject()` to notify them for an error. If you do not call these methods on the deferred, your listeners have no way to know you're done.

Comment: the function that runs before, and the function that runs after HAVE to run before and after or all will not happen as intended.  The first function (before updateGridRow) has several steps and can take some time.  I have no idea how long.  How do I ensure that each of those steps is completed before setting .resolve()?  I tried putting the daughter functions inside resolve, but it just skipped them.

Comment: In any asynchronous operation, there will be a way to define a callback that will be run when the operation is completed. That's when you're done, and that's where you would resolve your deferred so your dependents know you're done. If you're waiting on multiple operations, define multiple deferreds and wait on all of them with `$.when()`. This is getting tedious and appears to be devolving into an "implement the complete solution for me" scenario.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12767/discussion-between-davids-and-lanzz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to use [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function somethingAsynchronous() {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    // now, delay the resolution of the deferred:
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve('foobar');
    }, 2000);
    return deferred.promise();
}

somethingAsynchronous().then(function(result) {
    // result is "foobar", as provided by deferred.resolve() in somethingAsynchronous()
    alert('after somethingAsynchronous(): ' + result);
});

// or, you can also use $.when() to wait on multiple deferreds:
$.when(somethingAsynchronous(), $.ajax({ something })).then(function() {
    alert('after BOTH somethingAsynchronous() and $.ajax()');
});
```

If your functions simply make an AJAX request, you can just return the actual promise returned by `$.ajax()`:

```
function doAjax() {
    return $.ajax({ /* ajax options */ });
}

doAjax().then(function() {
    alert('after doAjax()');
});
```

Comment: I tried adding a .then to my function call (see my edit above), but it still doesn't work.  Will that work ONLY with an ajax call?

Comment: Of course it wouldn't work, if you haven't modified your functions to use deferreds. No, it will work with any function that returns a deferred. I took the time to write a full example, was I wasting it?

Comment: I thought the last section meant I could simply add .then.  Sorry.  I modified the code and don't get an error, but it still doesn't work.  See ADDITION 1

Comment: I can't add a manual delay because sometimes it will be a long delay and I don't know how long up front.  I don't want to delay indefinitely just because.  I simply want it to move to the next function once the first completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If Each of your function returns a state/function and then probably you could add a prototype to each state/function, then you would be able to call the functions like this, in fluent api way(method chaining).

```
runfirst().runSecond().runThird()
```

and so on.

Lemme try to build a sample.

**EDIT**

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/AQP5J/), if it fits your design

**EDIT 2**
I did not realise, you were talking about async method chaining. 
There is very good example [here](http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/). It was discussed in this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796375/designing-a-fluent-javascript-interface-to-abstract-away-the-asynchronous-nature)

Comment: Each function is a separate AJAX call.  Right now, they do not return anything, it simply calls the next in line.  However, if I need to make it return something I can.

Comment: I just tried your prototype but added a setTimeout to delay completion of stepOne.  stepTwo finishes before stepOne.  I wanted the .success to ensure they happen in order and the next doesn't start until the prior completes.

Comment: FWIW: One of your links says the technique he has is similar to currying. WRONG! The link he has that points to a "currying" article doesn't even curry at all. It does partial application though, which is related, but a far cry from real currying. When scrubs blog things they don't completely understand. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you really just want a better way to organize these callbacks. You should use a FIFO array or a queue. Your run all should do your stacking for you then execute the first function.

```
var RunQueue = function(queue){
    this.init(queue);
}

var p = RunQueue.prototype = {};

p.queue = null;

p.init = function(queue){
    this.queue = queue.slice(); //copy the array we will be changing it
                                // if this is not practical, keep an index
}

p.run = function(){
    if(this.queue && this.queue.length) {
        var first = this.queue[0];
        this.queue.shift();
        var runQueue = this;
        first(function(){ /*success callback parameter*/
            runQueue.run();
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var queue = [runFirst, runSecond, runThird, ...]

(new RunQueue(queue)).run();
```

If you really want to get fancy, and you may need to, you could pass in Objects in the array containing your parameters and have RunQueue append the last parameter as the success callback. You could even pass in the context to run the function in that object then call apply or call (whichever one uses the array) on your method.

```
{
    method: runFirst,
    context: someObject,
    parameters: [param1, param2, param3];
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand how to pass parameters.  Will you provide an example?  If I have understood the rest correctly, I create a RunQueue function, then call it as needed forcing the code to run synchronously.  Is that correct?

Comment: for the parameters, would it be like this: var queue=[{method:runFirst,parameters:[p1,p2,p3]},runSecond,{method:runThird,parameters:[p1,p2]}]  This would runFirst with passed parameters, run second (no params), run third with parameters...right?